# call method inside class without using static (PHP)

Tags: php, methods, static

Let's assume I have bundled up a lot of handy functions inside a class of handy functions like this,

```
class handyfunctions {
    public static function handyfunction1(){
        something;
    }
    public static function handyfunction2
    ...
}
```

and want to use one of them inside another class.

```
class object {
    $property1 = 'whatever'
    ...
    ...
    public function dosomething() {
        $this -> property1 = handyfunctions::handyfunction1();
    }
}
```

How can I remove the static tag of handyfunction1 in a good mannered way?
Is there a general approach to this?

Comment: If method is __not static__, then it is __dynamic__ and should be called using instance of class.

Comment: yes i know. but i think it's bad mannered to create an object of kind handyfunctins inside the object class

Comment: What is the problem of keep using static approach?

Comment: generally it is considered bad code to use static functions. for example it is hard to write tests for it.

Comment: Then start reading about "dependency injection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using traits. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can't be overridden
Object::handyfunction1();

Comment: I'm Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to write something  (maybe a class?) that stores all the 'handyfunctions'  and can Be used as the the class but doesn't use static functions. I also don't want to create an Object of Class "handyfunctions" Inside "object".

Comment: create a parent class and then extend or import it to use common functions defined inside parent class